# How to pass a value in django select form?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am creating an invoice application.
I have a model Receivables as

```
class Receivables(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    receivable_name=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    receivable_address=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
    receivable_email=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
    receivable_telephone=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
    receivable_VAT=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
    receivable_Service_Tax=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
    receivable_PAN=models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.receivable_name
```

Have a model serviceinvoice as

```
class serviceinvoice(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='invoice')    
    invoice_number=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    invoice_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    invoice_receivable=models.ForeignKey(Receivables)
    total_amount=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=20)
    total_amountwithtax=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return invoice_number
```

form.py for `serviceinvoice` model as

```
class createinvoiceform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=serviceinvoice
        exclude=('user',)
```

views.py for this form as

```
@login_required
def createinvoice(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        inv_form=createinvoiceform(data=request.POST)
        if inv_form.is_valid():
            new_form=inv_form.save(commit=False)
            new_form.user=request.user
            new_form.save()
            return HttpResponse('Invoice created')
    else:
        inv_form=createinvoiceform()
    return render(request,'account/createinvoice.html',{'inv_form':inv_form})
```

Now the issues I am facing are:

1. Rendered template does not show Receivalbe name instead it shows `self.user.receivalbe_name`
2. How do i show receivalbe_name only related to logged in user?

Comment: 1. Remove the quotation marks in `__str__` 2. How would you identify a logged in user?

Comment: You have a typo error in your question 'self.user.receivalbe_name'  shouldn't it be self.user.receivable_name. Also, when you say receivable_name related to logged in user, what exactly do you mean by it? How is it related?

Comment: @RajeshYogeshwar that is automatically generated by django. I have not coded it anywhere!!! Changed in return.

Comment: @KlausD. Done but not it gives erro 'User' object has no attribute 'receivable_name'

Comment: Thats because user has a one-to-many relationship to a separate class that has the name

Comment: First issue solved. Second is open.

Answer (score 0):

Second issue solved by putting following in views.py:

```
inv_form=createinvoiceform()
        inv_form.fields["invoice_receivable"].queryset=Receivables.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```